# Matlab calculate speech features(e.g. RMS)

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, wav, voice-recognition, feature-extraction

I need to calculate some features of speech in matlab. However I don't know which ones operations I need to perform after getting data from wavread function, before I can use feature formula(e.g. RMS formula).

One 1 website I just found this:

```
rmsVec(m) = sqrt(sum(wavData{m}(:).^2)/length(wavData{m}(:)));
```

But on the other one they used DFT and then some operations with real and imagine part of matrix/vector which I don't understand.

So how should it be?

I have voicebox library, but I didn't found there calculating rms.
My matlab version: R2009b

EDIT:

http://www.edaboard.com/thread163664.html  see hobgoblin and petejonze answers

Due to petejonze it shouldn't matter whether I use time or frequency domain but

```
[y, fs, aa] = wavread('C:\Users\lukasz\Desktop\semestr 7\inzynierka\dzwieki\uczace\dol\dol_50')
y1 = y(:,1)
Y1 = fft(y1)
rms1 = sqrt(mean(y1.^2))
rms2 = sqrt(sum(Y1.*conj(Y1))/size(Y1,1))
```

and the results:

```
rms1 =

0.0577

rms2 =

13.2706
```

So I'm little confused. Which one is correct?

EDIT 2:

Another example:

```
>> y = [1;2;3]

y =

 1
 2
 3

>> Y = fft(y)

Y =

6.0000          
-1.5000 + 0.8660i
-1.5000 - 0.8660i

>> rms1 = sqrt(mean(y.^2))

rms1 =

2.1602

>> rms2 = sqrt(sum(Y.*conj(Y))/size(Y,1))

rms2 =

3.7417

>> size(Y,1)

ans =

 3

>> Y.*conj(Y)

ans =

36
 3
 3
```

So this formula

```
sqrt(sum(Y1.*conj(Y1))/size(Y1,1))
```

is incorrect and it should be

```
sqrt(sum(Y1.*conj(Y1))/size(Y1,1)^2)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rmsVec(m) = sqrt(sum(wavData{m}(:).^2)/length(wavData{m}(:)));

This is correct.

> But on the other one they used DFT and then some operations with real and imagine part of matrix/vector which I don't understand.

You can ask about it, however you need to provide more details. What other website are you talking about, what exactly you don't understand there.

> I have voicebox library, but I didn't found there calculating rms.

If you use melcepst

http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/melcepst.html

You can specify E0dD to include energy (RMS)

```
          (2) c=melcepst(s,fs,'E0dD')   % include log energy, 0th cepstral coef, delta and delta-delta coefs
```

You can analyze the code to see what happens under the hood

> rms1 = sqrt(mean(y1.^2))

This is correct

> rms2 = sqrt(sum(Y1.*conj(Y1))/size(Y1,1))

This is wrong, it has to be sqrt(sum(Y1.*conj(Y1)))/size(Y1,1) where division goes after sqrt. Because FFT function in matlab does not scale on 1/sqrt(n) and thus non-symmetric. So sum(y.^2) = sum (Y.*conj(Y)) / n you need to divide after sqrt.

Comment: Edited my question. Could you check it ?

Comment: Your suggestion about size(Y1,1) = 1 is wrong. This expression in case of this wav file equals 52920. size(Y1, 2) is 1.

Comment: You need to check this better because 13.2706 / 0.0577 = 229.99306759098786 and 229.99306759098786 * 229.99306759098786 approximately equals to 52920. So the difference between rms1 and rms2 is exactly sqrt of file size which you forget to add to expression. Also, as you see FFT is not really necessary here, so first variant is preferred.

Comment: I edited with 1 more example and question about formula in frequency domain. Please look at it.